# While inside a docker swarm container, how do i determine which replica number a container is?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-container, swarm

Given that I have a docker swarm service named Whale with a replica count of 10

When the container starts

How can the runtime program determine which replica number it is?

IE: "I am whale replica 3 of 10"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be to tell it by an environment variable and make use of the template parameters supported by [docker service create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates).

The compose syntax would look like this.

```yaml
services:
  replicated-service:
    environment:
      REPLICA: "{{.Task.Slot}}"
```

If you need to use it as part of the `command` or `entrypoint` which does not support the expansion of Go Templates.  You can utilize the value within a shell.  (Note that `healthcheck.test` does not require this workaround as it defaults to `CMD-SHELL`)

```yaml
services:
  replicated-service:
    image: alpine/socat
    hostname: whale{{.Task.Slot}}
    entrypoint: [
      "/bin/sh", 
      "-c", 
      "exec socat tcp-listen:9092,fork TCP:whale$$REPLICA:9092"
    ]
    environment:
      REPLICA: "{{.Task.Slot}}"
    healthcheck:
      test: socat /dev/null TCP:whale$$REPLICA:9092
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
```

Also note the `$$` to escape the `$` from YAML processing.

Comment: My environment variable is treating {{.Task.Slot}} it as a {{.Task.Slot}} String

Comment: environment variables are always strings.

Comment: I've tried the above example but I was getting an error when trying to deploy using deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yaml <service>.

This was resolved by adding single quotes to template.
e.g.
`REPLICA: '{{.Task.Slot}}'`